# What is the relevance of the Note in [expr.context]/1

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

See below the highlighted note in [[expr.context]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.context#1):

> In some contexts, unevaluated operands appear ([expr.prim.req],
> [expr.typeid], [expr.sizeof], [expr.unary.noexcept],
> [dcl.type.decltype], [temp.pre], [temp.concept]). An unevaluated
> operand is not evaluated.
> **[Note 1: In an unevaluated operand, a non-static class member can be named ([expr.prim.id]) and naming of objects or functions does not, by
> itself, require that a definition be provided ([basic.def.odr]). An
> unevaluated operand is considered a full-expression. — end note]**

1. In relation to a non-static member function, how can it be used in an unevaluated operand?
2. What is the relevance of saying that an unevaluated operand is a full-expression?

Comment: _In relation to a non-static member function, how can it be used in an unevaluated operand?_ The note implies non-static data member, not function.

Comment: Then why does it say "naming of objects or functions" above?

Comment: The "non-static class member can be named" part pretty clearly refers to [**\[expr.prim.id.general\]/(2.3)**](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#general-3.3): "if that *id-expression* denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand." (Example: `sizeof(S::m)`)